# Managing complex object types on DWR

Tags: java, javascript, dwr

I read converters section

http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/server/configuration/dwrxml/converters/bean.html

but i can not find exact solution.

Can i manage my beans like this

```
public class User(){

    public int id;

    public String name;    

    public List<Car> cars;

   public Bag aBag;


}

public class Car {
     int rgbcolor;
     String model;
}

public class Bag {
     int price;
      String brand;
}
```

I mean if my beans contains fields as other object types, what should i do, should i fill the values manually? Or is managing these beans possible maybe using custom or standard converters?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the custom converter as following in **dwr.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dwr PUBLIC
"-//GetAhead Limited//DTD Direct Web Remoting 3.0//EN"
"http://getahead.org/dwr/dwr30.dtd">
<dwr>
  <allow>
    <create creator="spring" javascript="TestController">
        <param name="beanName" value="TestController"/>
    </create>
    <convert converter="bean" match="com.test.Car" javascript="car"/>
  </allow>
</dwr>
```